# Error checking storage configuration (centos 7)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, centos

I tried to install linux centos 7 (dual boot), this is the first time i install linux so i've been following some tutorial. In the installation destination I've got an error message *Error checking storage configuration*. I have unallocated disk in my disk management (64GB), when I tried to select it with 'Automatically configura partitioning' I got that error message with details *Unable to allocate requested partition scheme*. Please help me

Comment: You may have reached the partition limit for an MBR-formatted disc. Can you create a partition in the empty space on the current OS?

Comment: @AFH No I can't create partition, there's a message "The operation you selected will convert the selected disk to dynamic". How to solve this?

Comment: I've not met that message. You could try letting the conversion proceed, but not before you have done a full disc back-up, because the operation may lose everything. I am always nervous about changing disc and partition formats.

Comment: @AFH there's an error to after click Yes to that message, so I'm unable to change it.  Is there any solution for the partition limit?

Comment: See [this discussion](https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/143876-partitioning-problem.html). It is some time since I worked with MBR discs, so I can't give definitive advice, and I certainly don't want to be responsible for your creating an unbootable disc.

Comment: @AFH so those unallocated disk need to be partition right? because I saw tutorial before and they didnt partition the disk just using those unallocated disk

Comment: Not necessarily. If the conversion works successfully, the partition can be deleted again, but the resultant free space should allow the installer to create its partition when required.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Windows and check if you have a "Healthy (Recovery Partition)" of 539MB or so... Delete this partition and you are good to go.